# Let the user add his own Widgets in a customizable Dashboard?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, document, sitepages

I'm looking for a possibility to let the user add his own link, document, or file in a customizable Dashboard. So that he always sees the most relevant things for him.

Like this structure:

```
"Link 1"    "Document 1"        + (add another element)

   +            +                         +
```

Is this possible to program?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add only text/links to documents/files, you can use **Text web part** in SharePoint online using which you can add bullet points, headings, links, tables, etc. on site page.

**Reference**: [Add text, tables, and images to your page with the Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)

---

If you want to upload the actual files & develop a customizable dashboard, you have to develop a custom [SPFx web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

You can find some SPFx web part samples below which might help you to get started with:

[SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)

---

Here's one SPFx web part example where user is adding links dynamically: [Custom Links](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-custom-links)